# How to generate a random string without repeated characters?

Tags: linux, bash, macos, terminal, tr

Im trying to generate a password in Bash that matches MacOS password requirements and one of them is that it can't have repeated characters (aa, bb, 44, 00, etc).

I know i can use `openssl rand -base64` or `/dev/urandom` and use `tr -d` to manipulate the output string. I use `grep -E '(.)\1{1,}'` to search for repeated characters but if i use this regex to delete (`tr -d (.)\1{1,}'`), it deletes the entire string. I even tried `tr -s '(.)\1{1,}'` to squeeze the characters to just one occurrence but it keep generating repeated characters in some attempts.  Is it possible to achieve what i'm trying to?

P.S.: that's a situation where i cant download any "password generator tool" like pwgen and more. It must be "native"

Comment: Search `pwgen`.

Comment: Is sed "native"?: `echo 1a2aa3aaa4aaba5aaaaa | sed 's/\(.\)\1*/\1/g'`

Comment: What "MacOS password requirements" are you referring to?

Comment: `tr` does not handle regular expressions. You give tr _sets_ of characters

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I have no bash at hands to, but trying to help you.

What about iteratively grabbing the unique chars, eg. by

```bash
chars=$(openssl rand -base64)
pwd=

for (( i=0; i<${#chars}; i++ )); do
  if [[ "$(echo $pwd | grep "${chars:$i:1}")" == "" ]]; then
    pwd=$pwd${chars:$i:1}
  fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue might be that you have non-printable characters, so it's not *actually* repeated.  If you first get the first e.g. 30 characters, then delete any non-alphanumeric, non punctuation characters, then squeeze any of those characters, then from whatever is left get the first 20 characters, it seems to work:

`cat /dev/urandom | tr -dc '[:alnum:][:punct:]' | fold -w ${1:-30} | head -n 1 | tr -s '[:alnum:][:punct:]' | cut -c-20`

Output e.g.:

```
]'Zc,fs6m;wUo%wLIG%K
2O3Ff4dzi30~L.RH8jR0
sU?,WkK]&I;z'|eTSLjY
5gK]\H51i@Rtux.{bdC=
:g"\?5JsjBd1r])2^WR+
;{cR:jY\rIc&Q(2yo:|-
fFykmxvZ|ATX_l6L(8h:
^Sd*,V%9}bWnTYNv"w?'
6foMgbU6:n<*cWj2W=3&
*v39FWmB@LwE5O`a3C36
```

Answer (score 0):

You're getting close. tr doesn't use regex (but does use POSIX character classes).

Either of these will squeeze repeats:

```
tr -cs '\0'
tr -s '[:graph:][:space:]'
```

They differ only in how we refer to "all characters". First is "complement of null" second is all printable and all white space characters. There may be a neater way to specify "all characters".

Or using sed:

```
sed -E 's/(.)\1+/\1/g'
```

This both squeezes printable characters, and removes white space:

```
tr -ds '[:space:]' '[:graph:]'
```

Example for 32 non whitespace characters, with no repeats:

```
tr -ds '[:space:]' '[:graph:]' < /dev/urandom |
dd bs=32 count=1
```

Also, this example specifies a list of allowed characters (letters, digits, and `_.`), then squeezes any repeats:

```
tr -dc '[:alnum:]_.' < /dev/urandom |
tr -sc '\0' |
dd bs=32 count=1
```

Example output:

```
9mCEqrhHPwmq7.1qEky6qn4jqzDpRK7b
```

Putting dd at the end means we get 32 characters *after* removing repeats. You may also want to add `status=none` to hide dd logging on stderr.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a specific size requirement?  Other required characters?

How about -

```
openssl rand -base64 20 | sed -E 's/(.)\1+/\1/g'
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear if you don't want consecutive chars repeated or no repeated chars at all (*which in either case I don't think it's a good idea as it would make your passwords weaker and easier to guess*), but having said that

```
#! /bin/bash

awk -vN=20 '
{
    n=split($0,ch,"");
    for (i=1; i<n; i++) {
        a[ch[i]]++
    }
    n=0;
    for (c in a) {
        if (++n > N) {
            break;
        }
        printf("%c",c)
    }
    printf("\n")
}
' < <(openssl rand -base64 32)
```

this generated `N` length passwords without repeated chars from 32 random bytes (*that is N should be much smaller than 32*)